# How to form a uri string in Javascript or in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

when i Hardcode the username and password in the uri it works fine, the webview opens the required page and logs the user in, but when i try to append variables to the uri it does not work, it gives an error in login , the credentials are wrong.

Hardcoded and works fine:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView,AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component {




async getUsername(){
var username;
try {
username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
console.log('username'+username);
return username;

} catch (error) {
// Error retrieving data
username ="";
console.log('username'+username);
return username;
}

}

async getPassword(){
var password;
try {
password = await AsyncStorage.getItem('password');
console.log('password'+password);
return password;
} catch (error) {
// Error retrieving data
password="";
return password;
}
}
render() {

let pic = {

  uri: 'http://www.userlogin.php?username=react&password=react@123'

   };
return (

  <WebView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    scalesPageToFit={false}
    source={{uri:pic.uri}}
  />
);
```

Used Variables does not work:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { WebView,AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

    export default class Test extends Component {
    async getUsername(){
    var username;
    try {
    username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
    console.log('username'+username);
    return username;

    } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    username ="";
    console.log('username'+username);
    return username;
    }

    }

    async getPassword(){
    var password;
    try {
    password = await AsyncStorage.getItem('password');
    console.log('password'+password);
    return password;
    } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    password="";
    return password;
    }
    }
    render() {
    var usr=this.getUsername();
    var pass=this.getPassword();
    let pic = {

      uri: 'http://userlogin.php?username='+usr+'&password='+pass

       };
    return (

      <WebView
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        scalesPageToFit={false}
        source={{uri:pic.uri}}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working

Comment: it will not log in

Comment: Do console.log(usr, pass) before `let pic = {

      uri: 'http://userlogin.php?username='+usr+'&password='+pass

       };`

Comment: console.log('user'+usr,'pass'+ pass);
 'user[object Object]', 'pass[object Object]'

Comment: Since you are getting an object, it is a problem , you need a string to append

Comment: logs are executed in this order                                                                
 04-07 16:26:32.630 32092  4030 I ReactNativeJS: usernamereact
04-07 16:26:32.635 32092  4030 I ReactNativeJS: passwordreact@123
04-07 16:26:47.976 32092  4030 I ReactNativeJS: 'user[object Object]', 'pass[object Object]'                                                                                     i think before getUsername gets executed uri is assigned with null in place of usr..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did these changes in the code and it worked

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView,AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component {
state = {
username:'',
password:'',
};
componentDidMount() {
this._loadInitialState().done();
}

_loadInitialState = async () => {
try {
  var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
  if (value !== null){
    this.setState({username: value});

  } else {
    this.setState({username:''});
  }
} catch (error) {
    this.setState({username:'AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message});

}
try {
  var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('password');
  if (value !== null){
    this.setState({password: value});

  } else {
    this.setState({password:''});
  }
} catch (error) {
    this.setState({password:'AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message});

}
};

render() {
let pic = {

  uri: 'http://appsriv.com.bh-in-19.webhostbox.net/wp/user-login.php?username='+this.state.username+'&password='+this.state.password

   };
return (

  <WebView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    scalesPageToFit={false}
    source={{uri:pic.uri}}
  />
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `getUsername` as `async getUsername() { ... }`. which means would will need to `await` the result, e.g. `var usr = await this.getUsername();`.  The same is true for `getPassword`.

Unfortunately I don't think the `render` function can be `async` so you might have to rethink your approach a bit.  My advice would be to make your component cater for the missing values (you can return `null` to not render anything) until the data is available.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192621/reactjs-async-rendering-of-components) is using ajax, but the asynchronous behaviour is similar to your problem, so maybe it can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set username in state and use that after callback

So something like

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { WebView,AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

    export default class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          username: null,
          password: null
       }

    }
    async getUsername(){
    var username;
    try {
    username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
    console.log('username'+username);
    this.setState({username: username});

    } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    username ="";
    console.log('username'+username);
    }

    }

    async getPassword(){
    var password;
    try {
    password = await AsyncStorage.getItem('password');
    console.log('password'+password);
    this.setState({password: password});
    } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    password="";
    return password;
    }
    }

    getWebView() {
        var usr = this.state.username;
        var pass = this.state.password;
        if (usr != null && pass != null) {
             uri: 'http://userlogin.php?username='+usr+'&password='+pass;
             return(
             <WebView
              automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
              scalesPageToFit={false}
              source={{uri:pic.uri}}
              />
              );

        } else {
           return( <View></View>);
        }

    }
    componentWillMount() {

       this.getUsername();
       this.getPassword();
    }
    render() {

    return (

      <View>
        {this.getWebView()}
      </View>
    );
  }
```